# userChrome.css not updating in MacOSX

Tags: macos, firefox, css

I installed firefox then tried fixing tom my preferred settings.

I followed http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes & http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder to edit this file:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/bzbmcmrb.default-1506714662572/chrome/cat userChrome.css
.autocomplete-richlistbox {
        background: #042029 !important;
        color: #cb4b14 !important;
}

#urlbar {
  background: #042029 !important;
  color: #268bd2 !important;
}

#body {
    background: #042029 !important;
    color: #268bd2 !important;
}
#textarea {
  color: #268bd2 !important;
  background-color: #042029 !important;
}


~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/bzbmcmrb.default-1506714662572/chrome/
```

but the drop down address bar color is not being modified.